# What is the best way to design Seller, Category and Product tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I want to store a list of **Sellers**, who sell a certain **Category** of products each, and then, each Seller will have **Products** from these Categories.

What is the best way to design this? Currently, what I have is three tables, Seller, Category and Product designed in this way.

How do I link Seller and Category? I feel like I am creating too many relationships here.

One way would be to create a separate table with indices for SellerId and CategoryId. Also, I think I will need a separate table for SellerId and ProductId too. Is there a better way to approach this design?

1 seller can have multiple categories,

1 category can have multiple sellers,

1 category can have multiple products,

1 product can again, have multiple sellers,

1 product can have only 1 category,

and last,
1 seller can have multiple products.

[image]

Comment: Are the relationships many-to-many?  If any given `Seller` can have multiple `Category` records and any given `Category` can have multiple `Seller` records then they would need such a linking table between them.  What's unclear to me, then, is the `Product` relationships.  If a `Product` is owned by both a `Category` and a `Seller` then there's no guarantee of the integrity of that relationship.  That `Seller` might not be linked to that `Category`.  Should a `Product` be owned only by a `Category` perhaps?  And any `Seller` with that `Category` has access to that `Product`?

Comment: Yes. these relationships are many-to-many. So, I can go ahead and create a Junction table between Category and Seller, but I also need to store Products from specific sellers.
So, in essence, 
1 seller can have multiple categories,
1 category can have multiple sellers,
1 category can have multiple products,
1 product can again, have multiple sellers,
1 product can have only 1 category,
and last,
1 seller can have multiple products

[Updated the question with this use-case]

Comment: My concern is that these relationships can end up "lying" about each other. Seller 1 can be linked to Category A, but can have Product X which is in Category B. There's nothing in the structure to stop this from happening. Should Category really even be an entity in this case? Or just a lookup? Would the business logic be satisfied if, for example, Products are owned by Sellers (a FK to Seller on Product) and Products have Categories (a FK to Category on Product). This would create an *implied* link between Seller and Category, just as an aggregate of the Categories of the Seller's Products.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, I wanted to keep the Product entity free of duplicates. In this case, there might be Sellers A, B and C all of who are selling Product 1 from Category 'Books'. I will end up storing 3 product records in this case. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, consider this structure...

```
Seller
----------
ID
etc.

Product
----------
ID
CategoryID
etc.

SellerProduct
----------
SellerID
ProductID

Category
----------
ID
etc.
```

In this case:

1. Seller and Product are aggregate roots
2. A Seller can be linked to multiple Products
3. A Product can be linked to multiple Sellers
4. Category is an attribute of a Product
5. Sellers are "linked" to Categories implicitly by the Products they sell

Would a Seller ever need to be linked to a Category for which that Seller has no Products?  If not, this structure should do the trick.  If a Seller needs to be linked to another Category, that Seller simply needs to link to a Product of that Category.

By demoting Category to a value type instead of its own entity, you don't need to link other entities to it.